# Angular 4 Multiselect plugin that works with formControlName

Tags: angular

I'm searching for a multiselect plugin (i.e. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-multiselect-dropdown) but that can works with formControlName.

I have an attribute component (in which I'd like the plugin to work) that is used by other components to create forms based on dynamic form templates. That's why I had to go with this component.

The component :

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';
import { Attribute } from '../../models/attribute';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-attribute',
    templateUrl: './template.html',
    styleUrls: ['./style.css']
})
export class AttributeComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() attribute: Attribute;
    @Input() form: FormGroup;
    @Input() forceReadonly = false;
    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() {
    }

}
```

The view :

```
<div class="form-group" [formGroup]="form">
    <label [attr.for]="attribute.name">{{attribute.displayName}} <span class="mandatory" *ngIf="attribute.required === true">*</span></label>
    <div [ngSwitch]="attribute.type">
        <input *ngSwitchCase="'TEXT'" type="text" class="form-control" [id]="attribute.name"
            [formControlName]="attribute.name"
            [readonly]="forceReadonly ? true : attribute.readOnly"
            [required]="attribute.required"
        />
        <select *ngSwitchCase="'SELECT'" class="form-control" [id]="attribute.name"
        [formControlName]="attribute.name" [disabled]="forceReadonly ? true : attribute.readOnly">
            <option *ngFor="let opt of attribute.format.values" [value]="opt">{{opt}}</option>
        </select>
        <select *ngSwitchCase="'MULTISELECT'" class="form-control" [id]="attribute.name"
        [formControlName]="attribute.name" multiple="multiple" [disabled]="forceReadonly ? true : attribute.readOnly">
            <option *ngFor="let opt of attribute.format.values" [value]="opt">{{opt}}</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I cannot bind my multiselect component to a ngModel like the ones that I saw needed.

Could you please help me out ?

Thanks

Comment: Read this [Multiple-Selection](https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview#multiple-selection)

Comment: Ideally I'm looking for something based on bootstrap :). But thanks I'll check !

Comment: instead of passing `multiple="multiple"` pass `multiple` only

Answer (score 0):

perhaps this can help you. it's a simple select/ multi select component.

source:
https://github.com/xrobert35/asi-ngtools/tree/master/src/components/asi-select

documention:
https://ng-tools.asi.fr/views/showroom/asi-ngtools/components/asi-select